# Google login sha-1 key is not recognized

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth

I am using google login in my android app. In the google console, I have two OAuth's created to support my release key and debug key. The SHA-1 keyprints are different hence the double OAuths. My debug key is working fine. There is not a problem with it. However, the problem starts when I build my app with release key. When I put the app in the internal test section, nobody can log in with google.. I got "Unrecognized Source" error. I double checked my key prints on the console, and they are just fine. Is there anyone who had a problem like this, and if how do you fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: Google is signing the apps with his keystore. You need to write that sha-1 key to the console as well, and it can be obtained from play store under the app signing..